# What does "Then Satan Entered into him" mean?

Tags: john, satan

John 13:26-27

Jesus answered, “It is he to whom I will give this morsel of bread when I have dipped it.” So when he had dipped the morsel, he gave it to Judas, the son of Simon Iscariot. Then after he had taken the morsel, Satan entered into him. Jesus said to him, “What you are going to do, do quickly.

What does the Phrase
"Then satan Entered into him ". Mean?

Comment: See my other answer to the same question  >>  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/57127/was-judas-possessed-by-satan-in-john-1327/57144?noredirect=1#comment150536_57144

Answer (score 1):

Let us lay out the facts and groundings to rule out a few possibilities.

1. The Greek is no help for us here. "Entered" means "entered", it is the term used by the other gospel writers for demonic entering, but also so much more.
2. The devil had already put it in Judas' heart to betray Jesus previous to this (John 13:2)
3. Judas is a thief previous to this (John 12:6)

This means **we can rule out any conception of Satan simply using the body** of an innocent patsy. That is not what John wants us to think.

Nor does Judas act like one processed by a demon:

John 13:30 (KJV)

> 30 He then having received the sop went immediately out: and it was
> night.

John 18:2-3 (KJV)

> 2 And Judas also, which betrayed him, knew the place: for Jesus
> ofttimes resorted thither with his disciples.
>
> 3 Judas then, having received a band of men and officers from the
> chief priests and Pharisees, cometh thither with lanterns and torches
> and weapons.

Let us compare that to Luke's description of Legion (demon possession was a fact of the first century, we can trust that John agrees with other Gospel witnesses on that as on geography or architecture.)

> 29 (For he had commanded the unclean spirit to come out of the man. For oftentimes it had caught him: and he was kept bound with chains and in fetters; and he brake the bands, and was driven of the devil into the wilderness.)

Firstly, it is Judas who knew the place - John tells us - and not Satan. Secondly, no description of the demon-processed sound like the sort of men who would be leading a band of men, but they are wild men who throw themselves into the fire or go into the wilderness. **John does not intend for us to think Judas a demoniac.** If he had, he would have been much clearer on the subject.

**So what is meant?**

I think 1 Chronicles 21:1 is useful scripture about Satan here:

> And Satan stood up against Israel, and provoked David to number
> Israel.

It is Satan - here in Chronicles and John - who is the patsy; being used for God's glory. Satan is the provoker, which is understood in the 1st century by Christian writers like Paul (e.g. 1 Corinthians 7:5) and not an insurmountable force. This was a fact understood in the 1st century Christian milieu because of verses like this and the inter-Testament writings.

Thus, what John is referring to is that the temptations and the provocations and the evils and every other tool of Satan took hold of Judas and what was once a temptation (John 13:2) - and we know from other Gospels even a plan - had now begun to be an action. Judas - for example - had now no more pleasure in his supper and was looking for an opportunity to slip out. Judas was - almost willfully - **Satan's agent**.

Comment: Great Answer.  But you didn't exegete the Text itself.  Are you saying that The phrase '"satan Entered him". Isn't literal Possession. ?

Comment: @FaithMendel Satan no more possessed Judas to betray Jesus than Joseph possessed Pilate (in Mark 15:43) to get Jesus' body.  It is the same (common) word in both. The Bible tells us what men possessed of demon's look like, and it isn't Judas.

Comment: You have an Upvote already from me.  Your last reply seems to be at odds with the Greek. "eiserchomai".

Answer (score 0):

It is such an intensity of sinful intent, that all "breaks", so to say, to stop it are completely broken and made inoperative. Then, with God's permission, Satan has no barrier to fully govern human being, because the intent of the Satan and the human being coincide.

The last chance, the last "break" to stop Judas was the Lord showing him uttermost love and respect by giving specially to him the dipped bread, thus even distinguishing him from other apostles, as if giving him the final warning: "look, whom you are going to betray: the one who loves you and has done so many good things to you! Who appointed you as one of the closest to Himself". But since even this "break" did not work, then nothing could work, so Judas became altogether subjected to the evil powers.

Even had no Satan and demons existed whatsoever, still Judas could have followed his sinful intent, for our sinful passions can work quite independently from Satan and demons and do the same stupid and murderous things. Thus, had Satan entered or not entered in Judas, he could still have done the same ungrateful thing to his Lord and Teacher.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you expand on " for our sinful passions can work quite independently from satan..."

Comment: @FaithMendel Let me tell you a famous oriental anecdote: A butcher sold a rotten meat to a client at a high price; when the client left, the butcher felt a remorse and shame and addressed Allah: 'Sorry, a Shaitan has seduced me to do such a vile thing'. Shaitan, however, was invisibly standing there and having heard that, utterly offended, shouted to Allah: "That's a calumny! I swear, I was standing there and did nothing, it was he, the butcher alone who has done this". That's what I mean: our fallen nature's sinful urges can lead us to vile actions without Satan or his servants.

Comment: Well Understood.  Would that mean that the first Rebellion would have still happened even if Satan wasn't on the Scene ?

Comment: @FaithMendel Quite possible, for Satan was one of a high hierarchy (not highest though) angels and he was not seduced by any intellectual creature, but himself decided to arrogate himself to the place of God, be self-provider of happiness to himself, which was an ontological error. Then, having fallen, he invited to the same error Adam and Eve ("you will be like gods", i.e. self-providers of happiness without God). Could Adam have done the same without seduction by Satan? I think, quite possible; ontologically it is possible.